# Discord.js "Unexpected identifier" when trying to DM a user

Tags: javascript, discord.js, syntax-error

I'm making a custom bot for a server, and I made a banned word list. I'm trying to make it so it mutes them until they agree to the rules again. This is the code:

```
if(msg.split(" ").includes("asdf")){
  if(msg.deletable){
      msg.delete()
  if(!msg.member.roles.cache.get("777167323232469002")
     msg.member.send("You have been muted for saying a banned word. Please visit the rules and read all of our rules. React with a checkmark if you agree to all of the rules.")
          .then(sent =>{
            sent.react("✔️")
            let muted = msg.guild.roles.cache.get("759883236322574376")
            msg.member.roles.add(muted)
            sent.awaitReactions((reaction,user) => (reaction.emoji.name == "✔️"),
                        {max: 1}.then(collected => {
                        if(collected.first().emoji.name=="✔️"){
                            msg.member.roles.remove(muted)
                            msg.author.send("Thank you for agreeing to follow our rules. Please keep in mind breaking any rules will result in moderator punishment.")
                        }
            })

        )}
        
  }
  }
}
```

The output it's giving me:

```
msg.member.send("You have been muted for saying a banned word. Please visit the rules and read all of our rules. React with a checkmark if you agree to all of the rules.")
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, and I'm new to JavaScript. Could someone please help?

Comment: Your have poor syntax. I recommend installing a linter to help you with syntax errors

Comment: Yes, please use a linter or format your code better.
Most likely the issue is a missing bracket after if(!msg.member.roles.cache.get("777167323232469002"), but im fairly sure you did not intend the flow it would use, since your spacing suggests that msg.delete is the only action after msg.deletable, not the whole content in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is all over the place. I recommend either installing a linter, using an IDE that has syntax highlighting or both. That'll let you know if you're missing brackets and so on. I can recommend [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for the IDE.

I corrected the syntax but please make sure to do what I recommended above.

```
if (msg.split(" ").includes("asdf")) {
    if (msg.deletable) msg.delete();
    if (!msg.member.roles.cache.get("777167323232469002")) {
        msg.member.send("You have been muted for saying a banned word. Please visit the rules and read all of our rules. React with a checkmark if you agree to all of the rules.")
            .then(sent => {
                sent.react("✔️");
                let muted = msg.guild.roles.cache.get("759883236322574376");
                msg.member.roles.add(muted);
                sent.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name == "✔️"), { max: 1 })
                    .then(collected => {
                        if (collected.first().emoji.name == "✔️") {
                            msg.member.roles.remove(muted);
                            msg.author.send("Thank you for agreeing to follow our rules. Please keep in mind breaking any rules will result in moderator punishment.");
                        }
                    })
            })
    }
}
```